# Renewal Processes (Rolling a Fair Die)

Tags: probability, summation, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

What is the expected number of rolls until you see a 6 immediately followed by a 2?

Let $D_i$ = number observed on the $i^{th}$ roll

Assume $T_0=0$

Now let $T_1$ = min{$i\ge2$:$D_{i-1}=6$, $D_i=2$}

Hence, for $k=1,2,...$, let $T_k$ = time of the occurence of "6 then 2"

Then the $T_k$'s can be viewed as the renewal times of a renewal process, and all have the same distribution and are independent.

So, $M(n)=E(N(n))$, by definition. 
(M is the renewal function and N is the number of renewals on an interval)

Then, we have

$M(n)=E(N(n))$

$=\sum_{k=1}^n$ P(there is a renewal on time k)

$=\sum_{k=2}^n$ P($D_{k-1}=6$, $D_k=2$)

=$(n-1)(\frac1{36})$

Q: What do I do to get this last step? I do understand the steps needed to answer the question itself, I'm just not understanding the summation portion.

Comment: What is $n$? There is a limit of throws?

Comment: I believe n is related to N, or in other words, N(n)= number of renewals on the interval (0, n]. But it is not clearly stated in my notes.